# PSNR and int16 data type images

Tags: matlab

is this code right for calculating PSNR for int16 data types images?

```
function PSNR = PeakSignaltoNoiseRatio(origImg, distImg)

[M N] = size(origImg);
error = origImg - distImg;
MSE = sum(sum(error.^2)) / (M * N);
PSNR=10*log10(255*255/MSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `error` as a name for a variable. It's a Matlab routine.

Convert the int16-matrices into e.g. doubles before computing the "error": `double(variable)`.